# Search forms and URL parameters in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a search from with multiple optional fields, I don't feel I've handled this correctly in the past and want to know how to correctly handle this so that results will reload should a user refresh the page after going through the search form.

I have a form that people can use to search for clients, my users can search by **type**, **name**, **account number**

**type** is a required field

**name** and **account number** are optional fields.

I can use the `$routeProvider` to configure my routes something like:

```
.when('/clientSearch/:type/:accountNumber?/:name?', {
```

but if **account number** and **name** are optional how do I distinguish if only one of the two is being passed in? Some forms have multiple optional numeric/string fields.

Using `$location.search()` I can set the URL params, like:

```
$location.search( {type: type, accountNumber: accountNumber, 'name': name} )
```

Which is the preferred method, coming at this wrong?

How do you properly handle search forms and allow the same results to be fetched again if the page is refreshed?

Comment: They should be query params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you use query params.  In angular they are called `search` params:

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

And use like so:

```
// http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo

// To get:
$location.search()  // => {foo: 'bar', baz: 'xoxo'}

// To set:
$location.search('foo', 'yipee') // => {foo: 'yipee', baz: 'xoxo'}
```

To your questions:

> Which is the preferred method, coming at this wrong?

The preferred method is definitely to use query/search params

> How do you properly handle search forms and allow the same results to be fetched again if the page is refreshed?

Grab the params and define whatever is needed in your controller.  If you need params available to the view, you can do things like:

```
$scope.searchParams = $location.search()
```

Comment: Take care not to confuse `$location.search()` and native `Location.searchParams` (a.k.a. "query string params"), as these are two different things. `$location.search()` is concerned with _part of `Location.hash`_ while `Location.searchParams` are parsed values from `Location.search` (query string). The important part is, changing the `hash` doesn't reload the page like changing the query string.